# Method for Browsing 1000s of .eml Files in Thunderbird?

Tags: email, thunderbird, evolution, thunderbird-addon

I recently exported my entire e-mail collection. My e-mail service only exports to .eml format.

I now have a folder containing thousands of .eml files. I would like to be able to browse these e-mails offline efficiently using Thunderbird or Evolution if possible.

Various internet searches led me to install a Thunderbird extension called [ImportExportTools](https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools-ng/) NG v14.0.1. The documentation for this extension claims to support:

**Import all EML messages from a single folder**

However, no matter how I try, I cannot see a way to import the folder full of .eml files.

I also looked into Evolution, but also couldn't find a way.

I am running Linux with the GNOME desktop environment.

I am not insistent on keeping the files in .eml format, so if there is a solution that involves conversion please do suggest it.

I've tried at least the first 10 results Google gave me.

Comment: @Gantendo I've tried at least the first 10 results of that Google search. None of them work. Drag and drop is also not a solution.

Comment: Why is drag and drop not a solution?

Comment: @harrymc Nothing happens when I attempt to drag one of the .eml files into the  Thunderbird window. Are you on GNOME too?

Comment: @Gary: I'm on Windows and it just works here. Try to update to the [latest TB version](https://www.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/all/).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. Probably the Windows version is superior in some ways. Are you able to batch import using the extension I mentioned?

Comment: ImportExportTools NG can only import mbox files. Perhaps there exist some tool to create an mbox archive from a folder, but I haven't looked at this.

Comment: @harrymc Ok, if that's true then the documentation's claim is false and I'm back to the beginning. On Windows Thunderbird are you able to batch import 1000s of .eml files via drag and drop? Do the e-mails then persist in Thunderbird for easy browsing?

Comment: I summarized it all in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

ImportExportTools NG can only import mbox files (I have it installed).

To import into Thunderbird is simple :
Drag-drop the `.eml` files into any folder in Thunderbird.

If you upload thousands of emails into IMAP, this will be slow.

In my test, dropped `.eml` files were correct, and they persisted
across a few invocations of Thunderbird.

Comment: Okay. I'll boot into Windows and give it a try. This method definitely doesn't work on my Linux setup. Thank you.

Comment: I am able to open the individual e-mails in Windows there, but opening them that way---a separate window for every e-mail---is not practical. I'm basically just looking for an offline e-mail browser that looks and functions like gmail, but it seems like Thunderbird doesn't do this if the e-mails are stored locally.

Comment: I answered about Thunderbird, but site rules here don't allow software recommendations. You may try the site https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/.